# split text items in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array like the following

```
[
  "First sentence ",
  "Second sentence",
  "Third sentence {variable}",
  "Fourth sentence {variable} with other data {variable2}",
  "Fiftth sentence {variable} with additional data {variable2}",
  "Sixth sentence"
]
```

I want to split the items in the array with the following conditions

if there is a variable (curly bracket) and there is content after the variable, that line should be split into 2 lines. If there is no content after the variable it can be kept as it is.

For example following is the output i need

```
[
 "First sentence ",
 "Second sentence",
 "Third sentence {variable}",
 "Fourth sentence {variable}",
 "with other data {variable2}",
 "Fiftth sentence {variable}",
 "with additional data {variable2}",
 "Sixth sentence"
]
```

What i tried so far is as follows

```
convertLogicsArray(sentenceArray: string[]): string[] {
    const newSentenceArray: string[] = []
    for (const sentence of sentenceArray) {
      // Split the sentence into two parts at the variable.
      const parts = sentence.split('{', 1)
      // If there is text after the variable, make the sentence two lines.
      if (parts.length === 2) {
        newSentenceArray.push(parts[0])
        newSentenceArray.push(parts[1])
      }
      // Otherwise, leave the sentence as one line.
      else {
        newSentenceArray.push(logic)
      }
    }
    return newSentenceArray
  }
```

It does not return the exact response i need.

How can i form the array as shown in the question when provided with the original array

Comment: I am usually not a big fan of solutions with regex, but i think in this case, it could be useful. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result You can split by providing a regex split character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flat-map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the array, splitting each entry on a [lookbehind regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) matching your *variable* format

```js
const sentenceArray = [
  "First sentence ",
  "Second sentence",
  "Third sentence {variable}",
  "Fourth sentence {variable} with other data {variable2}",
  "Fiftth sentence {variable} with additional data {variable2}",
  "Sixth sentence"
];

const newSentenceArray = sentenceArray.flatMap((str) =>
  str.split(/(?<=\{\w+\})/).map((s) => s.trim()),
);

console.log(newSentenceArray);
```

I've also used `String.prototype.trim()` to remove the spaces after *variables*.

**Note:** [Lookbehind doesn't work](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in IE or Opera Mini if that matters

Comment: Thanks @Phil Just what i wanted. This solution is simple and straight to the point!

Comment: @CraZyDroiD just keep in mind that you're losing information with this due to the removal of space characters. Might not be what you want in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one line like this.

```js
let arr = [
    "First sentence ",
    "Second sentence",
    "Third sentence {variable}",
    "Fourth sentence {variable} with other data {variable2}",
    "Fiftth sentence {variable} with additional data {variable2}",
    "Sixth sentence"
]
console.log(arr.toString().replaceAll('} ','},').split(','))
```